# Find the max difference pair in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on some kata but I cannot pass all the test cases.

So the situation is:

Given any array, such as this array: `int[] a = {2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1}`, find the max difference pair in the array, in the meantime make sure the larger value is at the higher index than the lower value.

In this example: `10` is the largest element, `1` is the smallest, since `10` is at index `2`, `1` is at index `6`, so it does not count because the larger pair is at a lower index. So the correct answer is `a[0]`, and `a[2]`, max different is `10-2`.

Other requirement is array size `N` is between `1` and `1_000_000`, any given `a[i]` is between `-1_000_000` and `1_000_000`

I wrote code like this:

```
static int maxDifference(int[] a) {
    //test array size
    if (a.length < 1 || a.length > 1_000_000) return -1;

    int[] oldArr = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int max = a[a.length - 1];
    if (max > 1_000_000 || a[0] < -1_000_000) return -1;

    int min = max;
    for (int i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
        if (oldArr[i] < max) {
            min = Math.min(min, oldArr[i]);
        }
        if (oldArr[i] == max) break;
    }
    int result = min == max ? -1 : max - min;
    return result;
}
```

My logic is pretty much make a copy of the array and then sort the array, then loop it though, keep a pointer for max and min values, then get the result.

What is troubling me is I only know there are some test cases I didn't pass, but no hints on why it didn't pass. Can anyone give me some advise and what I may missing in this helper method?

Comment: I think, you overloaded the term *pair* a bit, did you mean *first and second element of the pair* (or similar)?

Comment: Your logic is faulty, since it is not guaranteed that the maximum value will be in the result pair. Think about when the value `10` would be the first element in the array in the example.

Comment: Is this a question from a code challenges website? If so, do they permit you to ask others to solve the problem for you?

Comment: @Bobulous I already submitted my code, the purpose of asking this question is for my own learning not for the code challenge. They have software to detect if I write my own code or used someone else from the internet

Comment: @OPK I suspect you were not supposed to change the incoming array. The name of your method does not imply that it will alter the input array.

Answer (score 17):

Basically you need to keep track of the minimum value found so far and the maximum diff found so far:

```
static int maxDifference(int[] a) {
    int minimum, diff = -1;
    if(a.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    minimum = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        diff = Math.max(diff, a[i] - minimum);
        minimum = Math.min(minimum, a[i]);
    }
    return diff;
    // depending on interpretation of requirements, above line might be wrong
    // Instead, use:
    // return diff > 0 ? diff : -1;
}
```

Comment: @JasonZ Then I don't understand your requirements. This code does exactly what you described. (Unless the details about array size and value ranges need to be enforced, I just assumed these were details of the expected data)

Comment: @JasonZ - what is the expected output for `{2, 1}`? and for `{}`? and for `{1}`?

Comment: @JasonZ and what about for `{2, 2, 2, 2}`?

Comment: Then that's the problem. My code returns `0` for all of these as it is right now... changing.

Comment: Not good enough.  If `diff` is -1 and `a[i] - minimum` is 0, you set `diff` to 0 but I think that's wrong.

Comment: @ajb - why would that be wrong? `{1, 0, 1}` should be `0` as far as I understand this.

Comment: `{1,0,1}` should be 1, not 0

Comment: @ajg, JasonZ, yes... sorry, meant `{1, 1}`

Comment: `{1, 0, 1}` should return 1, right?  (`a[2] - a[1]`)  I think the problem comes when there are no cases where `j > i` and `a[j] > a[i]`, but some of them are equal.  `{3, 3, 2, 1}`.  The requirements aren't really clear, but it seems to me that it should return -1 in that case, not 0.  We may need to see the exact wording of the question.

Comment: @IanMc This algorithm doesn't find the max value in the array.  And I think you're wrong, I think it _is_ solvable in O(n).

Comment: @Amit yes, `{1, 1}` runs into the problem where you have to make sure you interpret the question properly.  I think the result should be -1, because the original question says "make sure the larger value is at the higher index", which rules out equal values.  But it isn't clear.

Comment: @ajb If *that's* the correct interpretation, that would mean the returned value needs to be > 0 or -1. That's a minor change in the last part of the function (the `return...` statement...). I guess Jason can check that out and let me know :-)

Comment: I retract my statement; well done solving this in O(n); marking this up!

Answer (score 3):

If performance is not an issue (what I assume, since you are sorting the array which is probably not the most efficient implementation), this *simple* but easily readable piece of code should do the trick:

```
public static int maxDifference(int[] a) {
    long bounds = 1_000_000;

    int biggestDifference = -1;
    if (a.length > bounds) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(a[i]) > bounds) {
            return -1;
        }
        for (int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
            int difference = Math.abs(a[j] - a[i]);
            if (difference > biggestDifference) {
                biggestDifference = difference;
            }
        }
    }
    return biggestDifference;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this implementation is wrong.
Input: 8 19 3 2 7
Output: 11
Expected output: 17

Comment: The array should be actually sorted before the handling.

Comment: @Maksim expected value is 11. Algotithm is correct but also slow

Answer (score 0):

This finds the local minima and maxima and keeps track of the global minima and the position of the current maximum difference.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MaxDifference {
    private static long difference(
            final int[] array,
            final int minPos,
            final int maxPos
    )
    {
        assert( minPos < maxPos );
        assert( array[minPos] < array[maxPos] );
        return ( (long) array[maxPos] ) - ( (long) array[minPos] );
    }

    public static int[] maxDifference( final int[] array ){
        if ( array == null|| array.length < 2 )
            return null;

        // Position of global minima.
        int minimaPos                 = 0;
        // Value of global minima.
        int minimaValue               = array[0];
        // Position of minima for current maximum difference.
        int minimaPosForMaxDifference = 0;
        // Position of maxima for current maximum difference.
        int maximaPosForMaxDifference = -1;
        // Current maximum difference.
        long maxDifference            = -1;
        // Current position
        int pos                       = 0;


        while ( pos < array.length - 1 ){
            // Find the local minima
            while( pos < array.length - 1 && array[pos] > array[pos + 1])
            {
                pos++;
            }
            // Test if the local minima is the current global minima.
            if ( array[pos] < minimaValue )
            {
              minimaPos   = pos;
              minimaValue = array[pos];
            }

            // Find the local maxima
            while( pos < array.length - 1 && array[pos] <= array[pos + 1])
            {
                pos++;
            }

            if ( pos > minimaPos )
            {
                long diff = difference( array, minimaPos, pos );
                if ( diff > maxDifference )
                {
                    minimaPosForMaxDifference = minimaPos;
                    maximaPosForMaxDifference = pos;
                    maxDifference   = diff;
                }
            }

        }
        if ( maximaPosForMaxDifference == -1 )
            return null;

        return new int[]{ minimaPosForMaxDifference, maximaPosForMaxDifference };
    }

    public static String toDiffString( final int[] array ){
        final int[] diff = maxDifference( array );
        if ( diff == null )
            return String.format(
                    "%s has no maximum difference",
                    Arrays.toString(array)
            );
        else
            return String.format(
                    "%s has maximum difference of %d at %s",
                    Arrays.toString(array),
                    difference( array, diff[0], diff[1] ),
                    Arrays.toString( diff )
            );
    }
    public static void main( final String[] args ){
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{} ) );
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{ 0 } ));
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{ 0, 0 } ));
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{ 1, 0 } ));
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{ 2, 1, 0 } ));
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{ 0, 1, 2 } ));
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1} ));
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{5,0,3,1,4} ));
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{5,0,3,-1,4} ));
        System.out.println( toDiffString( new int[]{ Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE } ));
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
[] has no maximum difference
[0] has no maximum difference
[0, 0] has maximum difference of 0 at [0, 1]
[1, 0] has no maximum difference
[2, 1, 0] has no maximum difference
[0, 1, 2] has maximum difference of 2 at [0, 2]
[2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1] has maximum difference of 8 at [0, 2]
[5, 0, 3, 1, 4] has maximum difference of 4 at [1, 4]
[5, 0, 3, -1, 4] has maximum difference of 5 at [3, 4]
[-2147483648, 2147483647] has maximum difference of 4294967295 at [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that **Amit**'s solution works either working with minimum or maximum. The nice property using maximum is that you only need one extra function (`Math.Max`). For the unbelievers, just perform a Unit test and check. In any case, this is indeed solvable in O(n).

```
//using minimum (Amit's solution - vote him up!)
static int maxDifferenceWithMin(int[] a) {
    int minimum, diff = -1;
    if (a.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    minimum = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        diff = Math.max(diff, a[i] - minimum);
        minimum = Math.min(minimum, a[i]);
    }
    return diff;
}

//using maximum
static int maxDifferenceWithMax(int[] a) {
    int maximum, diff = -1;
    if(a.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    maximum = a[a.length - 1];
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        diff = Math.max(diff, a[i] - maximum);
        maximum = Math.max(maximum, a[i]);
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Maximum Difference in an Array

```
    static int MaxDiff(int[] inputArr)
    {
        int n = inputArr.Length;
        if (n < 1) return -1;
        int max = 0;
        int result = 0;
        int result2 = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < inputArr.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if (inputArr[i] > inputArr[i - 1])
                max = inputArr[i];
            else
                continue;
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
            {
                result2 = max - inputArr[j - 1];
                if(result2 > result)
                     result = max - inputArr[j - 1];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

> Main Method

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] inputArr = { 7,2,3,10,2,4,8,1 };
        Console.Write("Maximum Differnce is " + MaxDiff(inputArr));
    }
```

> Output
>   Maximum Differnce is 8

Comment: shouldn't max diff be 9 in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Old Post but still would like to answer so it may help someone.
Here is my code:

```
    int n = in.readInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i] = in.readInt();
    }
    int max = arr[n-1];
    int diff = 0;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
        else{
            diff = Math.max(diff, max-arr[i]);
        }
    }
    out.print(diff);
```

Logic here is to traverse from right and find maximum number. If number is less than the maximum find the difference (else part). If number is greater than maximum then that will become maximum number(if part). so we are finding difference in a sub array and updating it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
Arrays.sort(this.elements);
maximumDifference = this.elements[this.elements.length-1] - this.elements[0];
```

Comment: It would be good if you can add an explanation why this code solve the question. Is easy to read, but still is a good practice

Comment: Hi King,
Arrays.sort(int[] a) in recent JDK is implemented with Dual-pivot Quicksort algorithm which has O(n log n) average complexity and is performed in-place (e.g. requires no extra space).

Comment: "make sure the larger value is at the higher index than the lower value". Your code doesn't do that. You are not solving the problem